# Display Set of items in a list view

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view (to display items selected inside the cart) which should display items which are added in run-time. When i set the height of the list view to `wrap_content` it will only display the first item. This list view is inside a scroll view with some other widgets like buttons. There cannot be ant errors in retrieving values as when I change height to `500dp` it display all items correctly. How can i specify a height to the list view without using `wrap_content` since it is not working according my requirement? Thanks.

Comment: "This list view is inside a scroll view" it's probably issue

Comment: You know the height of one list item? You know how many you have? Simply multiply those and set the listview height to that number. You need a static value if you have a listview inside a scrollview.

Comment: can you post your layout.xml ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29742385/1518273

Comment: Thanks.. I try removing the scroll view but then it will only display the content that fits the screen.

Comment: ListView has a its own scrolling functionality. So just use a ListView and set height to match_parent or some fixed height

Comment: Can you please post your layout?

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing out on is refreshing the view.

You need to [View.requestLayout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout%28%29) once you make any changes to the content.This forces the view to redraw and will show all the items that you have added.

You can either do this in your ListView adapter if you are using a custom adapter(add it to the getView(..) method).

Or you can do it once an item is added to the adapter.

EDIT: For your situation,maybe you do not want the scroll view to occupy you entire screen.So set the layout boundaries for you scrollview and set the listview to `wrap_content`.This should provide you a scrollable layout in an area which you designate.If you want more specific help,please provide the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure try this: change the `@android:layout_below=""` property.

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Items Selected"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"
        android:textColor="#ffff6b30"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/carList"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
        android:smoothScrollbar="false"
        android:scrollingCache="false" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calculate Bill"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#fffff536"
        android:background="#ffff6714"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/carList"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete Item"
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:textColor="#fffff536"
        android:background="#ffff6714"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Refresh Cart"
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:textColor="#fffff536"
        android:background="#ffff6714"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:onClick="refreshButtonClick" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back to Main Menu"
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:textColor="#fffff536"
        android:background="#ffff6714"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:onClick="bakToMainButtonClick" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I removed it but still no change.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended but possible to put a ListView in a ScrollView.
If you nest a ListView in a ScrollView it will break the touch. They will behave strangely, it just won't work. If you want to have a scrollable ListView in a ScrollView, eg. to show some content below the ListView or to support small screens (think BlackBerry...), this might be a solution for you. ListView in ScrollView, both scrollable.
Also, the solution below is hacky. Don't blame me if it breaks your setting.
Disclaimer: This solution is put together by a variety of SO posts + some tweaking by me. I don't have the sources anymore though.

Make the ScrollView your head element in your xml and, put a Relative Layout in it and nest the ListView in that. Make the ScrollView match_parent and the ListView wrap_content.
The touch will be broken, so you have to use this special ScrollView (new Class in new File):

```
public class ScrollViewExt extends ScrollView {
    private ScrollViewListener scrollViewListener = null;
    public ScrollViewExt(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScrollViewExt(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ScrollViewExt(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setScrollViewListener(ScrollViewListener scrollViewListener) {
        this.scrollViewListener = scrollViewListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if (scrollViewListener != null) {
            scrollViewListener.onScrollChanged(this, l, t, oldl, oldt);
        }
    }
}
```

You saw me using a ScrollViewListener, make a Interface with this name and let your Activity or Fragment implement it (also new File, this time an Interface):

```
public interface ScrollViewListener 
{
    void onScrollChanged(ScrollViewExt scrollView, 
        int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy);
}
```

Next you have to implement the scrolling by yourself in your Activity or Fragment that uses the Layout. To implement the scrolling you have to know how large your content (ListView + other stuff) is, eg. by using a background image:

```
    //get the size of the image
    int bitmapWidth = yourBitmapWidth;
    int bitmapHeight = yourBitmapHeight;

    // set maximum scroll amount (based on center of image)
    int maxX = (int)((bitmapWidth / 2) - (displayWidth / 2));
    int maxY = (int)((bitmapHeight / 2) - (displayHeight / 2));


    // set scroll limits
    final int maxLeft = (maxX * -1);
    final int maxRight = maxX;
    final int maxTop = (maxY * -1);
    final int maxBottom = maxY;
```

This is where the RelativeLayout comes to use: You will use it as a fake ScrollView by setting a TouchListener to it.

```
    yourRelativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        float downX, downY;
        int totalX, totalY;
        int scrollByX, scrollByY;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
        {

            if(hasToScroll)
            {

            float currentX, currentY;
            switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    downX = event.getX();
                    downY = event.getY();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    currentX = event.getX();
                    currentY = event.getY();
                    scrollByX = (int)(downX - currentX);
                    scrollByY = (int)(downY - currentY);

                    if (currentY > downY)
                    {
                        if (totalY == maxTop)
                        {
                            scrollByY = 0;
                        }
                        if (totalY > maxTop)
                        {
                            totalY = totalY + scrollByY;
                        }
                        if (totalY < maxTop)
                        {
                            scrollByY = maxTop - (totalY - scrollByY);
                            totalY = maxTop;
                        }
                    }

                    if (currentY < downY)
                    {
                        if (totalY == maxBottom)
                        {
                            scrollByY = 0;
                        }
                        if (totalY < maxBottom)
                        {
                            totalY = totalY + scrollByY;
                        }
                        if (totalY > maxBottom)
                        {
                            scrollByY = maxBottom - (totalY - scrollByY);
                            totalY = maxBottom;
                        }
                    }

                    yourRelativeLayout.scrollBy(0, scrollByY);
                    downX = currentX;
                    downY = currentY;
                    break;

            }

            return true;

            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    });
```

Not quite done yet. We need to detect when which view should be allowed to scroll.

```
@Override
public void onScrollChanged(ScrollViewExt scrollView, int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {
    // We take the last son in the scrollview
    View view = (View) scrollView.getChildAt(scrollView.getChildCount() - 1);
    int diff = (view.getBottom() - (scrollView.getHeight() + scrollView.getScrollY()));

    // if diff is zero, then the bottom has been reached
    if (diff == 0) {
        isBottom = true;
        isTop = false;

    }
    else if(scrollView.getScrollY() < 10)
    {
        isBottom = false;
        isTop = true;

    }
    else
    {
        isBottom = false;
        isTop = false;

    }
}

public void scrollViewIsAllowedToScroll(Boolean isAllowed)
{
    scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(!isAllowed);
}
```

Should have set your Listview global, because you need to implement its scrolling by hand, too:

```
public void addOnTouchListenerToListView()
{       

    try{
    if((listView.getChildAt(listView.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom()) > listView.getHeight())
    {
        listView.setOnTouchListener(new ListView.OnTouchListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                Boolean alldown = false;
                Boolean allup = false;

                if (listView.getLastVisiblePosition() == listView.getAdapter().getCount() -1 && listView.getChildAt(listView.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= listView.getHeight())
                {
                    //The list is scrolled all the way down here
                    alldown = true;
                    alldown = false;
                }
                else if (listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0 && listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() >= 0)
                {
                    //The list is scrolled all the way up here
                    allup = true;
                    alldown = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // The list is scrolled anywhere between top and bottom
                    allup = false;
                    alldown = false;
                }

                // filter different touch events
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    {
                        // save the position where list was touched first
                        downXValue = event.getX();
                        downYValue = event.getY();

                        v.onTouchEvent(event);
                        return true;
                    }

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    {                       
                        v.onTouchEvent(event);
                        return false;
                    }

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    {

                        // get the current position of the touch
                        float currentY = event.getY();

                        // if the current touch position is smaller than the first touch, the touch (finger) has moved down, so the list has to scroll up
                        if (downYValue < currentY) {
                            direction = Constants.kDirectionDown;
                        }
                        // if the current touch position is bigger than the first touch, the touch (finger) has moved up, so the list has to scroll down
                        else if (downYValue > currentY)
                        {
                            direction = Constants.kDirectionUp;
                        }

                        // cases to figure out when the scrollView is allowed to scroll instead of the list
                        if(isTop && allup)
                        {
                            scrollViewIsAllowedToScroll(true);
                        }
                        else if(isBottom && allup)
                        {
                            if(direction == Constants.kDirectionDown)
                            {
                                scrollViewIsAllowedToScroll(true);
                            }
                            else if(direction == Constants.kDirectionUp)
                            {
                                scrollViewIsAllowedToScroll(false);
                            }
                        }
                        else if(isBottom && alldown)
                        {
                            scrollViewIsAllowedToScroll(false);
                        }
                        else if (!allup && !alldown)
                        {
                            scrollViewIsAllowedToScroll(false);
                        }
                        else if (isBottom)
                        {
                            scrollViewIsAllowedToScroll(false);
                        }


                        v.onTouchEvent(event);
                        return true;
                    }

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    {   
                        v.onTouchEvent(event);
                        return false;
                    }

                    default:
                    {
                        v.onTouchEvent(event);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        scrollViewIsAllowedToScroll(true);
    }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So, thats it. I don't know if its what you wanted, but it sure helped me a lot.

Edit: almoust forgot about this:
You need to call addOnTouchListenerToListView once, but only after waiting a short period of time, since your listView won't be filled immediatly. Also you might want to call this only once, since after that the ListView is still set.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    adjustScrolling();
}

public void adjustScrolling()
{

        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = null;
        runnable = new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   if(listView.getHeight() > 0)
                    {
                        firstStart = false;
                        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                        addOnTouchListenerToListView();
                    }
                   else
                   {
                       handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
                   }
               }
            };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);

}
```